# Can not get proper result for type casting in PHP

Tags: php, typecasting-operator

I have a Float variable

```
$float = 37.80
```

Then I multiply the float by 100:

```
$mul = $float *100
```

Now I have 3780.

```
$typecasting = (int) $mul;
```

Now when I print `$typecasting`, it shows 3779

For example:

```
$float = 37.80;
$mul = $float*100;
echo $mul;
echo '<br>';
//$mul = 3780
$typecasting = (int) $mul;
echo $typecasting;
// $typecasting shows 3779
```

I can't understand, how it works.
This problem occurs only for 32.80, 33.80, ...4.80. and also for multiples of 2, i.e. 65.60.

Comment: Floating points aren't perfect in any programming language. You found an example that shows this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples . This happens because binary isn't perfect for storing halves, eights, sixteenths, etc. Just as you can't write 1/3 in the decimal system properly, you can't store `37.80` in binary properly.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `floatval()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

```
$float = 37.80;
$mul = $float*100;
echo $mul;
echo '<br>';
//$mul = 3780
$typecasting = floatval($mul);
echo $typecasting;
// $typecasting shows 3779
```